# How can I get the timestamp of a XMPP chat message that's sent to Hubot?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, hubot

I'm using an Openfire server to support Jabber chat between Spark clients. I want to use GitHub's Hubot to monitor chatrooms and listen for users to send messages to Hubot, then log the messages. I'm having a hard time figuring out how I can get the timestamp of the message from the point of view of the Openfire server... is this even possible or should I just use the system time of the system running Hubot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the system time of the receiving process.  Only messages that were stored before you join a room will have timestamps with the server time.